# How can hexo order by created time

Tags: hexo

I'm using [hexo](https://hexo.io/) to create a blog. The posts are reordered each time I change the content of one of them, by modified time. It bothers me as I just want all the posts ordered by create time. Any hints would be welcome.

Comment: You are going to have to look into this order by function in the docs. https://hexo.io/docs/helpers.html#list_categories

Something like this, obviously length is not the right column.
<%- list_categories({orderby: 'length', order: 'desc'}) %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem as yours. Turned out the create date is updated somehow by hexo whenever you update it.

But if you set the `date` tag in the article description, hexo will keep it.

Here is an example:

```
---
title: Some title
tags:
- some tag
- some tag
- some tag
categories:
- some category
date: 2017-08-21 21:30:00
---
```